# alias template for member template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17, type-alias

let's say I have a template:

```
template<typename T>
struct Outer {
    template<typename T1>
    struct Inner {

    };
};
```

I'd like to have an alias template `Alias`:

```
template<typename T>
using Alias = Outer<T>::template Inner; // this won't work

using IntOuter = Alias<int>;
```

so that `IntOuter<double>` is same as `Outer<int>::template Inner<double>`. How do you define `Alias`? Or is it possible?

Edit:

I'd like to be able to create `SomeOuter` on the fly so that for template foo:

```
template<template<typename> class>
struct Foo {
};
```

`Foo<Alias<int>>` is same as `Foo<Outer<int>::template Inner>`

Or to do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
using SomeFoo = Foo<Alias<T>>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you are asking.

That is the answer to your question.  You ask a narrow question without sufficient background, that is the best I can do.

---

If you want to do serious metaprogramming in C++, you can transfer templates to types or values.  See the boost hana library for one approach.

But none will interact with

```
template<template<typename> class>
struct Foo {
};
```

"Out of the box".

```
template<class T>struct tag_t{using type=T;};
template<class T>constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};
template<template<class...>class Z>struct ztemplate_t{
  template<class...Ts>using apply=Z<Ts...>;
  template<class...Ts>
  constexpr tag_t<Z<Ts...>> operator()(tag_t<Ts>...)const{return {};}
};
template<template<class...>class Z>constexpr ztemplate_t<Z> ztemplate{};
template<class Tag>using type_t=typename Tag::type;
#define TYPE(...) type_t<decltype(__VA_ARGS__)>
```

Now

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto Alias = ztemplate<Outer<T>::template Inner>;
```

is now a value that acts like a template.

Mapping `Foo` to:

```
template<template<class...>class Z>
constexpr tag_t<Foo<Z>> foo( ztemplate_t<Z> ){return {};}
```

lets you do `TYPE( foo(Alias( tag<int> ) ) )`.

This is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 4):

You could

```
template<typename T, typename T1>
using Alias = typename Outer<T>::template Inner<T1>;

template<typename T1>
using IntOuter = Alias<int, T1>;
```

Or directly

```
template<typename T1>
using IntOuter = Outer<int>::Inner<T1>;
```

Then for `IntOuter<double>` you'll get `Outer<int>::Inner<double>`.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vJSSAkJaCM4wmMnB)

Comment: This one hard coded the outer template parameter. It's not exactly the same. I'll elaborate in the question.